# when to use -I in xargs

Tags: find, xargs

I have difficulties understanding how to use **xargs** especially using flag **-I**. I have two html files in my current directory

```
$ ls 
$ hello world.html    hi.html   junk
```

I know if I want to copy these two files into *junk* directory, I need to use **-I** to take the replacement of the stdin:

```
find . -name "*.html" -print0|xargs -0 -I {} cp {} junk
```

so I think if I want to make a zip of them, I just need to do the same thing:

```
find . -name "*.html" -print0|xargs -0 -I {} tar czf dest.tar.gz {}
```

However, this **only** zip up the *"hello world.html"*, but without **-I** it works:

```
find . -name "*.html" -print0|xargs -0 tar czf dest.tar.gz
```

I don't know why it works this way and hope somebody can help me out.

Comment: which one will give "unquoted blanks"? with replace-str or without?